# android Ripple Effect not Working

Tags: android

Trying to add ripple effect to a button but adding the resource to the buuton, makes the app crash.
have an xml file name ripple.xml in drawable-v21 folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="?android:colorControlHighlight" >

    <item android:id="@android:id/mask"
        android:drawable="@android:color/white" />

</ripple>
```

using it as a drawable in my button:

```
  <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:elevation="5dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            android:background="@drawable/ripple"
            android:textColor="@color/zone_orange"
            android:id="@id/verify_button"
            android:text="@string/verify"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

when i tried running my code, i get this error.

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #38: Error inflating class android.widget.Button
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at dejavu.appzonegroup.com.dejavuandroid.Fragment.PhoneRegistration.onCreateView(PhoneRegistration.java:38)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1786)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:947)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1126)
            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:739)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1489)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:454)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5295)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:828)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:644)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at dejavu.appzonegroup.com.dejavuandroid.Fragment.PhoneRegistration.onCreateView(PhoneRegistration.java:38)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1786)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:947)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1126)
            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:739)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1489)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:454)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5295)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:828)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:644)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f020064 a=-1 r=0x7f020064}
            at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2213)
            at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
            at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3579)
            at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:642)
            at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:107)
            at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:103)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at dejavu.appzonegroup.com.dejavuandroid.Fragment.PhoneRegistration.onCreateView(PhoneRegistration.java:38)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1786)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:947)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1126)
            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:739)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1489)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:454)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5295)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
```

How do i fixed this and where did i get it wrong ?

Comment: it will crash if you run that app on os below lollipop for that you have to write a different drawable in drawable folder

Comment: @VishwajitPalankar  on adding the ripple.xml to drawable folder, it still didn't work. The app still crash

Comment: On which Android version you are testing? Keep ripple.xml in v21 folder and create a new one without ripple effect for drawable folder.

Comment: you cant give ripple for api below 20 so keep the name of the drawable file as same but give different effect which is applicable for prelollipop

Comment: @Sharj i am testing on android 4.4.2 .

Comment: @CrowdStar ripple will only work over API level 21 (Android 5)

Comment: are there other ways to add ripple effect to view on prelollipop devices ?

Comment: There are many external libraries that can provide this effect look for any of the ripple library here http://snowdream.github.io/awesome-android/

Answer (score 2):

Your code is fine. Ripple only works on Lollipop so if you have a device which is on lower API than 21 then you should have regular selector with same name in drawable directory.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use the following:

```
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
                  android:color="?android:colorControlHighlight">
    <item android:id="@android:id/mask">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="?android:colorAccent" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</ripple>
```

in your ripple.xml